# As Manchu, if I westernize and then form Qing, will I go back To Chinese?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I am playing as Manchu. I have not yet reformed my government due to Nomad bonuses early in the game, but was preparing to do so, until I saw a Portugese colony forming in Indonesia, within my colonial range. Which means I'll be able to Westernize shortly.
If I Westernize, and then take the decision to form Qing, will I lose Western technology, and go "back" to Chinese?
If that is so, is forming Qing really worth of it then, in your personal opinion? (mind that I haven't reformed the govt yet)

Thanks!

Comment: In my experience, the Chinese penalty is compensated by the huge size of their country. It allows them to build many universities to lower the tech research cost. In the end, I was not the most advanced but more than the Ottoman and Russia.

Comment: you can only build one university mate

Comment: Really? I guess It's because I mostly played with mods, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Vincent Would you like a visit from the slap fairy?

Comment: @Sunspawn what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is **No**, if you westernize, and then form Qing, you will remain Western Tech. [although, my units are Asian - don't know if this is related]

Comment: The form Qing decision changes your unit types, so even if you were Yeren and had muslim units post-reformation thanks to magical pagan powers, you still go down to chinese.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, but I once Westernized Muscovy before forming Russia in a game and kept the Western technology after the tansition.

This may not be 100% conclusive as it concerns a diffrent cultural group,but I feel it is safe to assume that the mechanism would work the same in your case.

It kinda  makes sense to me that your technology type is attached to your nation regardless of name changes.

Comment: Before one of the many horde nerfs, Manchu could form Qing without reforming and move from horde tech to chinese tech automatically. Nowadays you have to reform anyway, so it is a moot question I think.